# Rails helpers or html tags?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, tags, html-helper

What would be used more preferably?
What will work faster?

For example I need create some link. What use? `<a>` or `link_to`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stylistically, you may prefer this

```
<%= link_to "Users", users_path %>
```

to this

```
<a href="<%= users_path %>">Users</a>
```

mainly because it doesn't mix the HTML tags with the ERB quite as bad. It all stays in ERB.

Another reason probably doesn't apply to your situation right now but could apply in the future. The more view helpers like `link_to` that you use, the more globally configurable your application becomes. You may end up wanting to use a plugin in the future that globally modifies how `link_to` works, but obviously it wouldn't apply if you used straight up `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

`link_to` every time, otherwise you can't take advantage of routes etc

Comment: This isn't really all that true because you can still use routes without `link_to`.

Comment: Fine. It's not strictly true, it is possible, but it's far messier and there's no good reason why you'd want to wrap a rails tag with the path within a HTML a tag.